# Storing pixel values of a greyscale video ,averaging them and then showing the resulting video

Tags: python, opencv

`n = 3
array = np.ones((n,n)) / (n*n)
n = array.shape[0] * array.shape[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Vzkm.png)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

```
if ret is True:
    print("newframe")
    gframe = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    dst = cv2.copyMakeBorder(gframe, 1, 1, 1, 1, borderType, None, None)
    blur = cv2.blur(dst,(3,3))
    if k == 1  :
        lastframe = gframe
        curframe = gframe
        nextframe = gframe
        newFrame = gframe
        k = 0
    else :
        lf = ndimage.convolve(lastframe, array, mode='constant', cval= 0.0)
        cf = ndimage.convolve(curframe, array, mode='constant', cval= 0.0)
        nf = ndimage.convolve(nextframe, array, mode='constant', cval= 0.0)

        lastframe = curframe     
        curframe = nextframe     
        nextframe = gframe


        b = np.zeros((3, 528, 720))
        b[0] = lf
        b[1] = cf
        b[2] = nf


        result = np.mean(b, axis=0)





        cv2.imshow('frame',result)
        cv2.imshow('frame2',gframe)
```

`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Vzkm.png)

I am trying to add all pixel values of a 3x3 pixel and then average them. I need to do that for every pixel and every frame and replace the primary pixel with the averaged one. However the way i am trying to do it makes it really slow and not really accurate.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your code. Add the code snippet instead of picture. And try to be more clear to explain your question. You may visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Maybe [this implementation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html) could help you, it's even in the package you already use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a convolution.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

a = np.random.random((5, 5))
```

a

```
[[0.14742615 0.83548453 0.67433445 0.59162829 0.21160044]
 [0.1700598  0.89074466 0.84155171 0.65092969 0.3842437 ]
 [0.22662423 0.2266929  0.47757456 0.34480112 0.06261333]
 [0.89402116 0.00101947 0.90503461 0.93112109 0.44817247]
 [0.21788789 0.3338606  0.07323461 0.28944439 0.91217591]]
```

Convolution operation with window size 3x3

```
n = 3
k = np.ones((n, n)) / (n * n)
n = k.shape[0] * k.shape[1]
b = ndimage.convolve(a, k, mode='constant', cval=0.0)
```

b

```
[[0.22707946 0.39551126 0.49829704 0.3726987  0.2042669 ]
 [0.27744803 0.49894366 0.61486021 0.47103081 0.24953517]
 [0.26768469 0.51481368 0.58549664 0.56067136 0.31354238]
 [0.21112292 0.37288334 0.39808704 0.4937969  0.33203648]
 [0.16075435 0.26945093 0.28152386 0.39546479 0.28676821]]
```

Now you just have to do it for the current frame, and the two prior frames.

--------  EDIT: For three frames -----------

For 3D you could write a convolution function like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48822437/503835), but its quite complex as it uses FFTs

If you just want to average across three frames, you could do:

```
f1 = np.random.random((5, 5)) # Frame1
f2 = np.random.random((5, 5)) # Frame2
f3 = np.random.random((5, 5)) # Frame3

n = 3
k = np.ones((n, n)) / (n * n)
n = k.shape[0] * k.shape[1]
b0 = ndimage.convolve(f1, k, mode='constant', cval=0.0)
b1 = ndimage.convolve(f2, k, mode='constant', cval=0.0)
b2 = ndimage.convolve(f3, k, mode='constant', cval=0.0)

# Create a 3D Matrix, with each fame placed along the first dimension
b = np.zeros((3, 5, 5)) 
b[0] = b0
b[1] = b1
b[2] = b2

# Take the average across the first dimension (across frames)
result = np.mean(b, axis=0)
```

There probably is a more elegant solution than this, but it gets the job done.

--------  EDIT: For Movies -----------

Based on all the questions in the comments I've decided to attempt to add some more code to help with implementation.

Firstly I'm starting out with these 7 consecutive stills from a movie:

[image: 7 stills from matrix reloaded]

I have not verified that the following code is bug proof or actually returns the correct result.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

# this is a function to do previous code
def mean_frames(frames, kernel):
    b = np.zeros(frames.shape)
    for i in range(frames.shape[0]):
        b[i] = ndimage.convolve(frames[i], k, mode='constant', cval=0.0)
    b = np.mean(b, axis=0) / frames.shape[0]
    return b

mean_N = 3 # frames to average
# read in 1 file to get dimenions
im = cv2.imread(f'{root}1.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
# setup numpy matrix that will hold mean_N frames at a time
frames = np.zeros((mean_N, im.shape[0], im.shape[1]))
avg_frames = [] # list to store our 3 averaged frames
count = 0 # counter to position frames in 1st dim of 3D matrix for avg
k = np.ones((3, 3)) / (3 * 3) # kernel for 2D convolution

for j in range(1, 7): # 7 images
    file_name = root + str(j) + '.png'
    im = cv2.imread(file_name, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
    frames[count, ::] = im # store in 3D matrix
    # if loaded more than min req. for avg, we average
    if j >= mean_N: 
        # average and store to list
        avg_frames.append(mean_frames(frames, k))
    # if the count is mean_N - 1, that means we need to replace
    # the 0th matrix in frames so that we are doing a 'moving avg'
    if count == (mean_N - 1):
        count = 0
    else: 
        count += 1 #increase position in 0th dim for 3D matrix storage

# ouput averaged frames
for i, f in enumerate(avg_frames):
    cv2.imwrite(f'{path}output{i}.jpg', f)
```

Then looking at the folder, there are 5 files (as expected if we did a moving average of 3 frames over 7 stills:

[image: contents after running the code]

looking at before and after:

Image 3:

[image: original #3]

and averaged image #1:

[image]

The image not only is in gray scale (as expected) but seems quite dark. Perhaps some brightening would make things look better/more apparent.

Comment: "No module named scipy". I feel doomed

Comment: pip install scipy ?

Comment: Yes thank you i should have known about that. I ll try to figure out a way for the previous and next frame to be added into the mix as well

Comment: Can you think of  a way that the processing is done in a 3x3x3 area?

Comment: @kristof I've made a change to my answer for 3D averaging. Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: That was very helpful thank you! i implemented this to my program and now i have a result that works. I seem to however have done something wrong and the frames are now mostly white.

Comment: I edited the code. I could try and play with it at this point till i can get it to a favourable result, but i would much appreciate any input on what i am doing wrong

Comment: @kristof I've done a ton for you already, answered your question, and you haven't marked my answer as an answer, or up voted it. You should incorporate the averaging code into your program and then create a new question for your new problems since this comment thread is not the place to resolve all these issues.

Comment: I tried to cast the votes but it didnt allow me to do that. You are right, i am sorry for the overwhelming spree of questions i am just really frustrated

Comment: @kristof you need to take a break from the PC man. go talk a walk, have a coffee, read something, then come back with fresh eyes. Right now, your code seems to be missing array definition, averages the same frame, and then draws gframe on top of the averaged result.

Comment: @kristof I've added some implementation with an example. I haven't checked the code to verify its accuracy, but I hope it at least helps you a bit.

Comment: I actually followed your instructions and went for a walk. i didn't expect to find that you still work on it. This is too much i cant thank you enough for your knowledge and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very interesting.

I saw that you use many loops for activating this function. Let's process analysis.

Just for a frame.

You want to add all pixel values of a 3x3 pixel neighborhood. So I think Image interpolation is very suitable for this case. In OpenCV, we use resize() to interpolate pixel for image. So the INTER_NEAREST is best for this situation.

[image]

[image]

This is the formula for INTER_NEAREST.

Now you get the pixel added image.

Then you want to do that for every pixel and every frame and replace the primary pixel with the average one. And I think the Average filtering is a better solution.

[image]
[image]

The filter will work every pixel.

The code of a temporary example.

## Interpolation

```
img = cv2.resize(img, (img.size[0]*3, img.size[1]*3), cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

## Filter

```
img = cv2.blur(img, (3, 3))
```

Comment: That looks like a good idea, however i dont know how to implement this on 3 different frames at the same time(previous-current-next).